# Only use cross fade in on a part of the sound

Tags: audio, audacity

I'm modifying sounds for a game purpose. Most of the sounds have too slow start, so mostly I need to cut off the silent beginning.

However, the beginning is not completely silent, so after cutting, I need to apply fade in effect on the sound, otherwise a crackly sound is audible in the beginning of the clip. That's because sound doesn't begin in 0dB.

Audacity's cross fade effect solves this issue quite well, however, it fades most of the sound - and that's not what I want. So I select only the beginning:

[image: Part of the sound selected]

And I apply the cross fade:
[image: Faded sound with an error]

As you can see, waves get damaged at the border of the faded zone. Can I fix this? I tried the paint tool but it was still audible.

As a replacement, I figured out, that I can cut the sound when the waves cross 0dB, but I want the fade effect. Also, it's quite tricky to pick wave's 0dB point because the audacity graph has no guides.

Comment: there's a fade-in and fade-out filter in Audacity too, you know. They don't damage the waveforms like that.

Comment: Didn't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stib said, one option is to use the built in `Fade-In` effect that comes with Audacity. To use it all you need to do is select the part of the track you want to fade in, and run the effect (which is located at `Effect>Fade-In`).

[image]

The above method may not suit your needs if you need more control over the fade-in. If this is the case, you should use the `Envelope Tool`. The `Envelope Tool` can be used to gradually increase or decrease the volume in a track (as shown in the image above). There is a good tutorial on how to use it over [HERE](https://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/audacity/envelope-tool/).